# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home", tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run server browser show me something like this:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Rake routes shows me this:

```
root  /                  static_pages#home
help  /help(.:format)    static_pages#help
about  /about(.:format)   static_pages#about
contact  /contact(.:format) static_pages#contact
```

My routes.rb file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'static_pages#home'

match '/help',    :to => 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',   :to => 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', :to =>'static_pages#contact'


end
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: There is no route for /static_pages/home (although your home action is at / ). What were you expecting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no route set for the url '/static_pages/home'

Although root points to static_pages controller with action home, it still responds to the path '/' and not '/static_pages/home'

If you add

```
match '/static_pages/home', :to =>'static_pages#home'
```

You will get the expected response for '/static_pages/home'

Answer (score 5):

step 5.3.3 [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#fig-about_page)

You don't have to refresh your page

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/home
```

but only change the URL by

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

because you define 'static_pages/home' as root '/'.

For me it works

Answer (score 2):

I just got the same error as szatan when I followed the Ruby on Rails tutorial.
The error is because, previously, we test URL was `http://localhost:3000/static_pages/help` since the action is in static_pages. But, after changing `routes.rb` from

```
get 'static_pages/help' to
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help
```

The URL should changed to `http://localhost:3000/help`
since we tell Rails server to route the path `/help` to `static_pages#help`. We shouldn't expect the user to know the path `/static_pages/help`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to remove the *"public/index.html"* file.

You can define all the routes properly, but if you leave this file, you won't be routing it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I got to this point in the tutorial.  It was resolved when I pointed the browser to `"http://localhost:3000/"` and reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could point to `"/"` or `root_path` in stead of `'/static_pages/home'`. No need to point two routes to the same place...

Answer (score 0):

you should add :as keword to define XXX_path,such as 
root :to => 'static_pages#home'

```
match '/', to: 'static_pages#home', :as => :home
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help', :as => :help
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about', :as => :about
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', :as => :contact
```