# No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home.html.erb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am following Michale Hartl's tutorial and I am currently at this step:

*Listing 5.23. Adding a mapping for the root route. config/routes.rb*

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
root to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

I have copied his exact coding to my config/routes.rb and continue to get a Routing Error:

### Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home.html".

--

Not sure what to do at this point to get my home routed as the index, and to be able to use root_path to link back to 'Home'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710424/routing-error-no-route-matches-get-static-pages-home-tutorial  Are you requesting `/static_pages/home.html`? Or are you requesting `/` from the browser?

Comment: Rake routes log:    root  /                  static_pages#home
   help  /help(.:format)    static_pages#help
  about  /about(.:format)   static_pages#about
contact  /contact(.:format) static_pages#contact

Comment: just to be sure, do you have a `home` action on your `StaticPagesController` ?

Comment: class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
  
  def about
  end
  
  def contact
  end
end

Comment: Thanks Michael, followed the directions in the link you provided and it now works!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `../static_pages/..` from the URL you've entered in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

this code is correct

SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

```
root :to => 'static_pages#home'

get '/help' => 'static_pages#help'

get '/about' => 'static_pages#about'

get '/contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

end

You do not have to delete the index page, the rspec test in the tutorial is not wrong, this is the updated code with current available methods

describe "Home page" do

```
it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do

  visit '/'

  page.should have_content('Sample App')

end
```

end

This is using ruby -v ruby 2.0.0p47 and rails -v Rails 4.0.3

you can also get a failure if your using before { visit help_path }, using the Rails Console and checking the path app.help_path confirms 'before { visit help_path } is correct but if this code is not in spec/rspec_helpers.rb then the test will fail because it cannot find the path

Named routes should work if you put the following in rspec_helper.rb:

Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end

Answer (score 0):

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'static_pages#home'
get '/help' => 'static_pages#help'
get '/about' => 'static_pages#about'
get '/contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

this code is right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete or rename the public/index.html and then it will work.