# Route error in rails demo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, aptana3

I have created a simple hello world application in Rails (4.1.4) in Aptana Studio 3.

The problem is whenever I am running the server and try to access localhost:3000, everything is fine but when I try to access the application with localhost:3000/greet/index, I get the following error message :

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/greet/index"
>
> Rails.root: D:/WorkSpace/demo_rails
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   Routes
>
> Routes match in priority from top to bottom
>
> You don't have any routes defined!
>
> Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.
>   For more information about routes, please see the Rails guide Rails Routing from the Outside In.
>
> Helper HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
>   Path / Url

Comment: Please show us your config/routes.rb file.

Comment: Hi,i have nothing there in routes.rb , everything is commented.

Comment: If you have nothing in your routes, what is `/greet/index` supposed to do?

Comment: greet is my controller name and index the following method. I have a index.rhtml file also. /greet/index is just supposed to print a text in the browser that's all.

Comment: I am trying to follow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710424/routing-error-no-route-matches-get-static-pages-home-tutorial .. but getting the same routing error.

Comment: @andrey i have defined a route greet/index to root, but still the same. I know i am missing something very silly, just don't know which one, writing rails for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read error message. It says you do not have any routes. Open the recommended in error message materials and read those.
2. add `root to: 'greet#index'` to routes.

---

Recommendation: always check error message carefully, Rails are smart enough to provide you with fully helpful hints in those.

Comment: i have a root entry as root for greet/index i.e root 'greet#index' as a result now when i run localhost:3000, it gives me "template is missing". I think the next step is to create a template ? Also, i have index.rhtml file in app/views..doesn't it serves the purpose as a template ?

Comment: so the initial problem is solved. Try changing name to  index.html.erb and find some info for how to use erb.

Comment: Thanks..i got this silly issue fixed. Apologies for the same.

Comment: out of the forum question..could you please suggest me some good rails 4 tutorial..i was following an old tutorial..

Comment: Sure. http://www.railstutorial.org/book this one is the most popular among beginners. Also go carefully (gradually) through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.6/ - extremely useful, so always appeal to it when you have general questions.